# How to join two different queries into one query using Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join, compare, subquery

I am trying to join two queries for comparing the results of 2 semester for students using Code Igniter(CI).

I could do it directly using MySQL but how to do it using CI?

Following is the query for MySQL:

```
select x.student, x.2017, y.2018 from (SELECT a.student_id student, sum(a.marks) 2017 FROM a a 
WHERE a.year = '2017' GROUP by student
) x
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT b.student_id student, sum(b.marks) 2018 FROM b b
WHERE b.year = '2018' GROUP by student
) y on x.student = y.student
```

How can this be done in CI?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it's working.

```
    $this->db->query("select x.student, x.2017, y.2018 from (SELECT 
    a.student_id student, sum(a.marks) 2017 FROM a a 
    WHERE a.year = '2017' GROUP by student
    ) x
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT b.student_id student, sum(b.marks) 2018 FROM b b
    WHERE b.year = '2018' GROUP by student
    ) y on x.student = y.student");
```